# Download live DBPedia on “is [property] of”?

Tags: dbpedia

I want to download all the properties of an entity in the `http://pl.dbpedia.org/page/`, but when I choose the RDF (N-triple) to download the raw data about an entity, I found that the "is [property] of" properties missing, so how can I get all the properties including the "is [property] of"? Thanks!

For Example, I want to get the raw data(N-triple) of [`http://pl.dbpedia.org/page/Robin_Wright`](http://pl.dbpedia.org/page/Robin_Wright).  How can I get the "is starring of" property?

Answer (score 0):

"`is [property] of`" is a presentation of inverse relationships.

```
{  <http://pl.dbpedia.org/resource/Robin_Wright>  is ?property of  ?subject  }
```

-- corresponds to --

```
{  ?subject  ?property  <http://pl.dbpedia.org/resource/Robin_Wright>  }
```

You can get these with SPARQL queries like this, which will include all triples with that entity as object --

```
SELECT ?s ?p
WHERE 
  {  ?s  ?p  <http://pl.dbpedia.org/resource/Robin_Wright>  }
```

-- or this, which will include all triples with that entity as subject *and* as object --

```
DESCRIBE <http://pl.dbpedia.org/resource/Robin_Wright>
```